# Beginner Challenge: Sum all even numbers 1-1000. Is my rationale wrong or just my code?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dojo, sum

I just began coding the other day and I'm going through coding dojo's free beginner algorithm course. I had no trouble with the intro lesson predicting outputs, but now I am writing code my thoughts don't seem to translate well.

The task is to write a function that would get the sum of all the even numbers from 1 to 1000. They mentioned I could use the modulus operator, but I think that operator is a little contrived. Instead I figured it easier and more efficient to run a For loop, starting at 0 and adding 2 each loop. After each loop the new number would be added to the previous which would be the current sum variable. I have attached my attempted solution:

```
function sum_even_numbers(){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var x=2; x!=1000; x+2)
    {
      sum+=x;
    }
    return sum; 
}
```

Unfortunately this only freezes my browser until I stop script (I guess it's on an infinite loop). Most of the previous lesson work involved outputs using console.log() and I'm not even sure why I can't use it instead of the return operator. Can tell me if my way of going about solving the problem is valid or not and if it is, what's wrong with the code. And if it's not, where the flaw is in my logic. I have included the suggested solution below.

```
function sum_even_numbers(){

    var sum = 0;
    for(var x = 1; x < 1001; x++){
      if(x % 2 === 0){
      sum += x;
      }
    }
    return sum; 
}
```

Thanks all

Also if you have time, why does a semicolon after the If operator change the answer so much? I still don't know the hard rules of semicolon use.

Edit: Thanks guys, what a great community!

Comment: I can't see this question and *not* mention that, according to legend, the great mathematician Gauss figured out how to solve a very similar problem with a single addition followed by a single division...  *while he was in primary school.*  Hint: 2+4+6+...+1000 = 1000+998+996+...+2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop is incorrect.
You have

```
for(var x=2; x!=1000; x+2)
```

Where you should do

```
for(var x=2; x<=1000; x = x+2)
```

Currently, your loop never updates x so it has the same value all the time. Statement 3 in the for loop is executed as it is so your code just executes x+2 which is just some number. The code I suggested above updates x to be equal to x+2.

Your condition terminates the loop once x is equal to 1000 so 1000 is not added to the sum. You need to either break the loop when x is equal to 1002 or better use

```
x<=1000
```

Putting a semi-colon after the if condition means that you want to do nothing if that condition is satisfied. If you don't put a "{" after the if then only one statement following the if statement is executed when your condition is satisfied. When you put a semi-colon, then you execute an empty statement.

Comment: You should also note the use of the relational operators in for loops

Comment: Ohhhh thank you!. I know you can just do x++ so I didn't think you needed at = when you more than increment.


Also, x!=1000 gives me a slightly off answer. I need to do x<=1000 in order to be correct. Why would not equal to 1000 be different than less than or equal to 1000?

Comment: x++ is equivalent to x = x + 1.
Actually your condition terminates the loop once x is equal to 1000 so 1000 is not added to sum. You need to do x <= 1000 so that the condition is satisfied as long as x is less than or greater to 1000. You can also use x!= 1002.

Comment: @Dinamo788 because `x!=1000` doesn't satisfy the `x==1000` part of `x<=1000`

Answer (score 1):

Really, there's no reason you actually have to run the loop, since this function always returns the same number.

```
function get_the_sum()
{
    //Sum of even numbers <= 1000
    //=(1000+0 + 998+2 + 996+4 ... + 0+1000) / 2
    return 500*501;
}
```

Comment: So can you say `return (input/2) * (input/2+1);` for any maximum input? (Just to make the code a bit more generic...)

Comment: it's javascript, so you you need to use Math.floor(input/2), but yes

Comment: Oh right. I guess even though I said "any" I was assuming the max would be an even number itself.

Answer (score 0):

No need for looping at all. With an O(1) function that sums the range from 1 to N, you can easily derive the even and odd sums as well:

```
function Adjust(n) { 
   return n % 2 === 0 ? n : --n;
}

function SumRange(n, m) {
   if (n > m) 
       return 0;
   var sum = (m * ++m) >> 1;
   return n > 1 ? sum - SumRange(0, --n) : sum;
}

function SumRangeEven(n, m) {
   var sum = SumRange(Adjust(n), m >> 1);
   return sum + sum;
}

function SumRangeOdd(n, m) {
   return SumRange(n, m) - SumRangeEven(n, m);
}

console.log(SumRange(0,101)) //5151
console.log(SumRangeEven(0,101)) //2550
console.log(SumRangeOdd(0,101)) //2601
console.log(SumRangeEven(0,101) + SumRangeOdd(0,101)) //5151
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to make sure you increment the loop properly. Other than that, your reasoning seems perfectly right. 
You are doing:

```
for(x=0;x!=1000;x+2)
```

whereas you should be doing something like:

```
for(x=0;x<=1000;x+=2)
```

Here, `a += b` is a shortcut for `a = a + b`. Also, `<=1000` includes 1000 in the sum as well.

As for your second question, a semicolon after an if statement invalidates an if statement as if no `{}` are placed after an if statement, it only executes the condition on the statements till it encounters its first semicolon.
If you have more than 1 line of code to execute in if statement you may implement it like this:

```
if(condition) {
    code line 1;
    code line 2;
    code line 3;
}
```

Comment: So a semicolon cancels or ends a condition. So I need to wait until after I include the if statement condition and end the whole set with a semicolon? Got it!

Comment: Yup. That would be the case if you only have one statement of code to execute in condition.

Comment: @Dinamo788 - You don't need a semicolon after the closing `}` of an `if` block.